# Mapstruct cannot support Generic type

Tags: java, generics, mapstruct

I want to convert IPage from mybatis-plus to PageDto using mapstruct.

But mapstruct complains: Can't generate mapping method for a generic type variable source。

The code is as follows:

```
@Mapper
public interface PageDtoMapper<T> {

    @Mapping(source = "total", target = "total")
    @Mapping(source = "pages", target = "pages")
    @Mapping(source = "records", target = "records")
    @Mapping(source = "current", target = "pageNum")
    @Mapping(source = "size", target = "pageSize")
    PageDto<T> toPageDto(IPage<T> page);
}
```

or:

```
@Mapper
public interface PageDtoMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "total", target = "total")
    @Mapping(source = "pages", target = "pages")
    @Mapping(source = "records", target = "records")
    @Mapping(source = "current", target = "pageNum")
    @Mapping(source = "size", target = "pageSize")
    <T> PageDto<T> toPageDto(IPage<T> page);
}
```

PageDTO:

```
public class PageDto<T extends Serializable> {
    private Long total;
    private Long pages;
    private Long pageNum;
    private Long pageSize;
    private List<T> records;
}
```

[IPage](https://github.com/baomidou/mybatis-plus/blob/3.0/mybatis-plus-core/src/main/java/com/baomidou/mybatisplus/core/metadata/IPage.java)

Can I use generic type in Mapstruct?

Answer (score 1):

Mapstruct generates type-safe code. I think it cannot be achieved if there is a type parameter left in the mapper interface.

Even if it forces you to define as many mapping methods as record types you use, this should work :

```java
@Mapper
public interface PageDtoMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "total", target = "total")
    @Mapping(source = "pages", target = "pages")
    @Mapping(source = "records", target = "records")
    @Mapping(source = "current", target = "pageNum")
    @Mapping(source = "size", target = "pageSize")
    PageDto<RecordType> toPageDto(IPage<RecordType> page);
}
```